# Android - How to get size of / length / number of items in a ListFragment?

Tags: android, android-listfragment

For example, something like...

```
int numItemsInMyListFragment = myListFragment.size();
```

...that is obviously valid??

**Update:** I've just discovered the answer by doing a similar search for ListActivity, so I'll post the answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int numItemsInMyListFragment = myListFragment.getListView().getCount();
```